# TensorFlow JS - Load A Model Generated Using Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I followed the steps in [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras) to convert a trained `TensorFlow` model generated using `Python`. Now I want to use that to re-create the model in `TensorFlow JS`. I passed the path for `model.js` like this:

```js
const model = tf.loadLayersModel(pathToModelsDotJSON).then(() => {
    // Do stuff
})
```

I'm using `Vue.js` and when I run the code it throws this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `inputShape` or `batchInputShape` argument.
    at new t (tf-layers.esm.js?271e:17)
    at t.add (tf-layers.esm.js?271e:17)
    at t.fromConfig (tf-layers.esm.js?271e:17)
    at deserializeKerasObject (tf-layers.esm.js?271e:17)
    at deserialize (tf-layers.esm.js?271e:17)
    at eval (tf-layers.esm.js?271e:17)
    at eval (tf-layers.esm.js?271e:17)
    at Object.eval [as next] (tf-layers.esm.js?271e:17)
    at o (tf-layers.esm.js?271e:17)
```

**My question is: Why is this happening? And how to solve it?**

Comment: The error says it all; you need to add batchInputShape to your first model. It might not be necessary in Python but in Js it is

Comment: @edkeveked And how do I pass it? Should I pass it in the same call to `loadLayersModel()`?

Comment: You have to pass it in your python code when you define the model

Comment: @edkeveked Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You're using the wrong function `modelFromJSON` to import the model. According to the tutorial, here is the function to use: `loadLayersModel`.

2-

> The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `inputShape` or `batchInputShape` argument

You need to add batchInputShape or InputShape to the model defined in Python